# Redis Error while buliding app for DigitalOcean/Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I have my application deployed on DigitalOcean server and I am using dockers for deployment. Everytime when I build and deploy application by using following command

```
docker-compose build && docker-compose stop && docker-compose up -d
```

I get this error

`ERROR: for redis  Cannot start service redis: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint redis_1 (1ed1d7aa7d6e2f166777beb1f55d65bc217e734671da600fec26db113168914f): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:6379: bind: address already in use`

I am using `elasticsearch`, `sidekiq` and `redis` images in my rails application.

Please help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

The command `docker-compose stop` stops running containers without removing them. That's why you are getting an above error. Containers are stopped and bounded to their ports.

The command `docker-compose down` should be used instead which stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by `docker-compose up`.

The final command is:

```
docker-compose build && docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: I tried the command, but not worked. I am still getting same error

Comment: What is the output of `docker ps -a` on the host?